# laravel assocation issue with user model

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the association ads table with users how I can show the users
data. It shows me error trying to get property of non object
association.

Tables:

1. ads
2. users (default Laravel)

In User Model:

```
    public function ads()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Ad','user_id');
    }
    In Ad Model
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    in Routes
Route::get('/ads',function(){
      $ads = Ad::get();
      //print_r($ads);
   foreach ($ads as $ad) {
          echo $ad->user->name;// issue here

   }
});
```

It prints this array when I `print_r($ad->user)`;

> App\User Object ( [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => name [1] => phone [2] => email [3] => password [4] => role ) [hidden:protected] => Array ( [0] => password [1] => remember_token ) [connection:protected] => [table:protected] => [primaryKey:protected] => id [perPage:protected] => 15 [incrementing] => 1 [timestamps] => 1 [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => irfan [email] => irfan0786@gmail.com [phone] => 43434 [password] => $2y$10$dnUuC9yxQwSHcpWy1oZlpuxaU33eBz1VYCPFQgfJYtncDivmDfqym [role] => User [remember_token] => x3l3x1tkXUB3I7KiRggPRclnCR5JGnDLlzCxZxeAmfpGCYFR0ylSrKNwSSuy [created_at] => 2016-06-12 17:42:36 [updated_at] => 2016-06-22 03:26:28 ) [original:protected] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => irfan [email] => irfan0786@gmail.com [phone] => 43434 [password] => $2y$10$dnUuC9yxQwSHcpWy1oZlpuxaU33eBz1VYCPFQgfJYtncDivmDfqym [role] => User [remember_token] => x3l3x1tkXUB3I7KiRggPRclnCR5JGnDLlzCxZxeAmfpGCYFR0ylSrKNwSSuy [created_at] => 2016-06-12 17:42:36 [updated_at] => 2016-06-22 03:26:28 ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [dateFormat:protected] => [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [with:protected] => Array ( ) [morphClass:protected] => [exists] => 1 [wasRecentlyCreated] => )

Answer (score 0):

To get all the ads you should use, `Ad::all()` not `Ad::get()`.

Update your `Ad` model as one user has one ad:

```
public function ads()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Ad','user_id');
}
```

Comment: i did it when i do Ad::all() it gives me same issue. i want to print user name echo $ad->user->name; but this line of code not working all other okay. when i print array  $ad->user it shows me data. but don't know how to extract it.

Comment: it prints whole array

Comment: share the array data please

Comment: i share it with you above in answer. any how thanks for help sumon

Comment: remove the answer and instead post the array data in your question by editing it.

Comment: this issue producer.  Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). but user has many ads but add belongs to one it should print the then name. because one ad is link with one user. how can i do it if i have something not correct above.